# Replace comma with dot Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

Given a fairly long array that looks like the following, I want to replace commas with dots:

```
array(['0,140711', '0,140711', '0,0999', '0,0999', '0,001', '0,001',
       '0,140711', '0,140711', '0,140711', '0,140711', '0,140711',
       '0,140711', 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, '0,140711', '0,140711'], dtype=object)
```

I've been trying different ways but I can't figure out how to do this.
Also, I have imported it as a `pandas` DataFrame but can't apply the function:

```
      1-8        1-7
H0   0,140711   0,140711
H1     0,0999     0,0999
H2      0,001      0,001
H3   0,140711   0,140711
H6          0          0
H8   0,140711   0,140711
H9   0,140711   0,140711
H10  0,140711  0,1125688
```

My code:

```py
df.applymap(lambda x: str(x.replace(',','.')))
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda x: str(x.replace(',','.')))` does work, replaces comma to dot on  `pd.__version__ == '0.18.1'`

Comment: Did you assign back the result? `df =df.applymap(lambda x: str(x.replace(',','.')))`

Comment: Also it'd be quicker to do this for each column: `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.'))`

Comment: Great @EdChum. I didn't assign back the result. Btw, apply is faster than applymap()?

Comment: `apply` works column-wise or row-wise, `applymap` operates on each element so yes in this case `apply` would be faster. You could also do `df.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()`

Comment: I'm not sure if something has changed in Pandas since this was posted, but a simple `%timeit` shows that `applymap` is faster than `apply`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to assign the result of your operate back as the operation isn't inplace, besides you can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with vectorised [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) to do this quicker:

```
In [5]:
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.'))

Out[5]:
          1-8        1-7
H0   0.140711   0.140711
H1     0.0999     0.0999
H2      0.001      0.001
H3   0.140711   0.140711
H4   0.140711   0.140711
H5   0.140711   0.140711
H6          0          0
H7          0          0
H8   0.140711   0.140711
H9   0.140711   0.140711
H10  0.140711  0.1125688
H11  0.140711  0.1125688
H12  0.140711  0.1125688
H13  0.140711  0.1125688
H14  0.140711   0.140711
H15  0.140711   0.140711
H16  0.140711   0.140711
H17  0.140711   0.140711
H18  0.140711   0.140711
H19  0.140711   0.140711
H20  0.140711   0.140711
H21  0.140711   0.140711
H22  0.140711   0.140711
H23  0.140711   0.140711

In [4]:    
df.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()

Out[4]:
          1-8        1-7
H0   0.140711   0.140711
H1     0.0999     0.0999
H2      0.001      0.001
H3   0.140711   0.140711
H4   0.140711   0.140711
H5   0.140711   0.140711
H6          0          0
H7          0          0
H8   0.140711   0.140711
H9   0.140711   0.140711
H10  0.140711  0.1125688
H11  0.140711  0.1125688
H12  0.140711  0.1125688
H13  0.140711  0.1125688
H14  0.140711   0.140711
H15  0.140711   0.140711
H16  0.140711   0.140711
H17  0.140711   0.140711
H18  0.140711   0.140711
H19  0.140711   0.140711
H20  0.140711   0.140711
H21  0.140711   0.140711
H22  0.140711   0.140711
H23  0.140711   0.140711
```

the key thing here is to assign back the result:

`df = df.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()`

Comment: this will NaN integer values on the dataframe

Comment: This fails for large dataframes

Answer (score 63):

If you are reading in with `read_csv`, you can specify how it interprets decimals with the `decimal` parameter.

e.g.

```
your_df = pd.read_csv('/your_path/your_file.csv',sep=';',decimal=',')
```

From the [man pages](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **thousands : *str*, *optional***
>
> Thousands separator.
>
> **decimal : *str*, *default ‘.’***
>
> Character to recognize as decimal point
> (e.g. use ‘,’ for European data).

Comment: Sweet! With previous suggestions I was getting errors with treating my data as strings.

Comment: It does not have the same effect that what the person is asking. By doing so when using to_dict on the dataframe for exemple, it will export with a comma decimal separator while it should be dot.

Answer (score 28):

If you need to replace commas with dots in particular columns, try

```
    data["column_name"]=data["column_name"].str.replace(',','.')
```

to avoid 'str' object has no attribute 'str' error.

Comment: why does .str.replace work for me but .replace doesn't?

Comment: @Fisqkuz it's been a while and you probably know it already by now but you have to pass as regex. I added an [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77123986/19123103) that includes a demo. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.replace()` (not `str.replace()`) by passing the conversion mapping as `regex=` parameter.<sup>1</sup> Good thing about this method is that unlike `str.replace()`, it can change multiple columns vectorially. There are a number of ways you can pass the same parameters.

```py
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(regex={',': '.'}).astype(float)
#                           ^^^^ <- pass as regex ^^^ <--- probably need to cast as float

df[cols] = df[cols].replace(regex=',', value='.')

df[cols] = df[cols].replace(',', '.', regex=True)
```

A demonstration of the method is as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['0,140711', '0,0999', '0,001'],
    'b': [0, '0,1125688', '0,1125688'],
    'c': ['0,140711', '0,1125688', '0,140711']
})
df = df.replace(regex={',': '.'}).astype(float)


          a         b         c
0  0.140711  0.000000  0.140711
1  0.099900  0.112569  0.112569
2  0.001000  0.112569  0.140711
```

---

<sup>1</sup> By default, `replace()` scans the values as a whole; so `.replace({',': '.'})` can make a replacement only if a value in a cell is a comma. Passing `regex=` signals to pandas to scan the individual strings in each cells as well. A consequence is `df.replace(regex={',': '.'})` is much slower than `df.replace({',': '.'})` but of course the latter won't make the correct replacements.