# Change Numbers from "81,33" to "81.33" with FOR loop

Tags: python, pandas

I need to change a big amount of data in a column from e.g. "81,33" to "81.33". Is it possible to change "," to "." and execute it with a For Loop for all values in one column?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083266/replace-comma-with-dot-pandas

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

```
float_numbers_as_strings = ["81,33", "44,55", "6565,4", "50,0", "5"]
float_numbers_as_strings = [number.replace(",", ".") for number in float_numbers_as_strings]
```

You can do it in a for loop and use `replace`. In my example I did the shorthand version of the for loop.

Comment: That doesn't use pandas