# Convert a column's values to numeric with European delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, delimiter

Consider this sample data frame `df_1`:

```
index    value_1

1        -3.570,00
2        +552,76
3        -1,01
4        -100.234,01
```

where the float values are signed, and European delimiters/separators have been used:

- comma `,` for decimal
- dot/point/period `.` for thousands

I want to convert the values of this column to float. If I try the instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648923/4999991)

```py
# tag 1
df_1['value_1'] = df_1['value_1'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

I get the error message:

> ValueError: Unable to parse string "<...>" at position <...>

I could use the instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083822/4999991)

```py
# tag 2
df_1['value_1'] = df_1['value_1'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('.',''))
df_1['value_1'] = df_1['value_1'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','.'))
```

before `# tag 1`, however, I get the message:

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11992\3059588848.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
...
```

Even though this workaround does the job, I wonder if there is a more canonical way to achieve what I want without getting any warnings.

Comment: @wjandrea any way to remove the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning too?

Comment: There's an existing question about that: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](/q/20625582/4518341). I don't have any experience with it myself, but I just googled "pandas SettingWithCopyWarning" and that looks promising.

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, had seen that page. couldn't comprehend it to a concise answer to my question though.

Comment: Oh actually, I can't reproduce the issue. Instead I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'` at `x.str`. If I switch `.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(...))` for `.str.replace(...)`, then I don't get any warning, but maybe my kernel is set up differently, IDK.

Comment: @wjandrea true. There was a mistake in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083822/4999991). please check the latest edit above.

Comment: I still don't get a warning. Even with `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = 'raise'`, nothing. I'm using Pandas 1.4.2 if that's relevant.

Comment: @wjandrea hmmm  are you on Windows OS? I am also using Jupyter.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm trying a chained assignment and it's failing silently. This seems to be an issue on my side.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `locale` module. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#module-locale)

Example:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'eu')

df.value_1 = df.value_1.apply(locale.atof)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     value_1
0   -3570.00
1     552.76
2      -1.01
3 -100234.01
```

Comment: what does `es` stands for?

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani Modified my answer to use `eu` for `European Union` instead of `es` for `Spanish`.

Comment: For some reason, I get the `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting` error! So, I posted a less elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading from CSV, you can use the `decimal` and `thousands` parameters:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., decimal=',', thousands='.')
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **thousands : *str*, *optional***
>
> Thousands separator.
>
> **decimal : *str*, *default ‘.’***
>
> Character to recognize as decimal point
> (e.g. use ‘,’ for European data).

*<sub>Due credit to [atomh33ls](/users/1461850/atomh33ls) for posting [almost exactly this](/a/56024892/4518341) on another question.</sub>*

Answer (score 0):

To convert the values in the DataFrame `df_1` to floats while handling European number formats (where commas are used for decimal points and periods for thousand's separators) and to avoid the `SettingWithCopyWarning`, we can use a more direct approach with Pandas.

The warning I was seeing is typically related to Pandas being unsure if we're modifying a copy of a slice from a DataFrame or the original DataFrame itself. To avoid this, it's often better to use `.loc` or `.apply` in a way that makes it clear we're operating on the original DataFrame.

Here's a more canonical and concise way to handle the conversion without triggering warnings:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'value_1': ['-3.570,00', '+552,76', '-1,01', '-100.234,01']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert European number formats to float
df_1['value_1'] = df_1['value_1'].str.replace('.', '').str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)

print(df_1)
```

This code does the following:

1. Removes thousand's separators (`.`) using `.str.replace('.', '')`.
2. Replaces the decimal comma with a decimal point using `.str.replace(',', '.')`.
3. Converts the modified string to a float using `.astype(float)`.

By chaining these methods, we efficiently transform the data into the desired format and apply the changes directly to the DataFrame, thus avoiding the warning.